# How to get specific TD text of parent TR in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my table, I have row for Category and when it expands, subcategories open in new `tr` and there I have input field for min and max price and save button. I have a `td` with text `"total price"` in main category `tr`. When I fill input field and press save, data is saving and in response back I'm getting updated object with total_price. Total price `td` is in upper `tr`. How can I reach to upper `tr` to change `td` text for total price if I have multiple sub categories rows.

I have given class `.header` to main category `tr`.

```
 <tbody>
 <tr class="header">
     <td id="total_price">100</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>sub 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="min_price"></td>
    <button>save</button>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>sub 2</td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="min_price"></td>
    <button>save</button>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>sub 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="min_price"></td>
    <button>save</button>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 $('#save').click(function(){
 ajax(data);
 var tr = $(this).prevUntil('tr.header');
 tr.find("td[id='total_price']").text(data.data.total_price);  
 });
```

This is not effecting at all, Can anyone please suggest something to me and.

Comment: The selector for an id would be `td#total_price` that being said, if you have multiple rows with that td, you can't be using an id as all ids int he dom must be unique.  Perhaps consider using a class and then you can select with `tr.find('td.total_price')` if that is in fact a header with an id, you don't have to find it, just select it with `$('td#total_price')`

Comment: I have only one td for price and that's why I used Id and it's in  current  header and I need to update that in DOM for better understanding im updating html as well,

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one element with that id, all you need to do is select it. Since I don't have your save code, I made some minor changes to show in this example, it has issues, e.g. if non numbers are in the boxes etc, but it gives you the idea.

```js
$('#save').click(() => {
  var total = 0;
  $('input[name="min_price"]').each((i, obj) => {
    total += parseFloat($(obj).val());
  });
  $('#total_price').text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td id="total_price">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="min_price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 2</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="min_price"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 3</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="min_price"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="save">save</button>
```

Comment: Button is inside every row.

Comment: I see that you have it that way, but you need to wrap them in a td element, you can't have a button inside a tr by itself. This example is just to demonstrate how to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snippets of code, you should always use valid HTML so that your jQuery script works fine.

```js
$('table button').click(function(){
  // Get the value of the closest input to the 'save' button
  var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
  var $totalPrice = $('#total_price');
  
  // Get the current existing value of the total price
  var currentVal = parseInt($totalPrice.text());
  
  // Condition check if the inputs are empty but still we click the save button
  if(typeof val !== 'undefined' && val != '') {
    val = parseInt(val);
    
    // Add the price to the total price
    $totalPrice.text(currentVal + val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
       <td id="total_price">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="min_price"></td>
      <td><button type="button">save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 2</td> 
      <td><input type="number" name="min_price"></td>
      <td><button type="button">save</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub 3</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="min_price"></td>
      <td><button type="button">save</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```